# match() is not working with Number field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to perform an action on rows that have specific words in email column by filtering it using the regular expression.

[image]

Problem is that `match()` produces the following error

`TypeError: Cannot find function match in object 1234. (line 25, file "Code")`

**My code**

```
    function smartDelete() {
    // smartDelete settings goes here, 
    var badDomains = ["bad\\.com", "red\\.com"];

    var emailColumnNumber = 2;

    var regExpModifiers = "i";

    // Gain access data in the sheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();
    var rowsDeleted = 0;
    var Action = false;

    // delete procedure
    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
        var row = values[i];
        Action = false;

        // check bad domains
        for (var j = 0; j <= badDomains.length - 1; j++) {
            var myPattern = new RegExp(badDomains[j], regExpModifiers);
            var status = row[emailColumnNumber].match(myPattern);
            if (status) {
                // match found, mark this row for delete
                Action = true;
                break;
            };
        };

        // execute delete.
        if (Action) {
            sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
            rowsDeleted++;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: You should include the error message, not just that there was an error.

Comment: Just added the `error` message to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match()` has to receive a string, cell `C4` produces a `Number`, hence the error.

Change this line,

`var status = row[emailColumnNumber].match(myPattern);`

Into the following should fix the `TypeError`

> Notice the `.toString()` method ahead of `.match()`

`var status = row[emailColumnNumber].toString().match(myPattern);`